# Object has no attribute Error when calling __getattribute__ on singleton object

Tags: python, getattribute

This is singleton object I implemented quickly (very similar to second example from [The Singleton template](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html)).

```
class Model(object):
  class __Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = None

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self) + self.val

    instance = None

    def __new__(cls):  # __new__ always a classmethod
        if not Model.instance:
            Model.instance = Model.Model()
        return Model.instance

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name):
        return setattr(self.instance, name)

    def __getattribute__(self, bool_custom_trained):
        return getattr(self.instance, bool_custom_trained)

    def __setattr__(self, bool_custom_trained):
        return setattr(self.instance, bool_custom_trained)
```

I'm using that object in two scripts. In first

```
print(self.model.__getattribute__('bool_custom_trained'))
```

Printing and setting attribute value works fine, but in second I can't use value, generated  **error** is:

```
    **print(self.model.__getattribute__('bool_custom_trained'))
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'bool_custom_trained'**
```

What should I check?

Comment: None of this makes any sense. There's so much wrong and so much context missing that we can't tell what any of it *should* have looked like.

Comment: There's no `Model.Model` class, I don't know why `Model.__Model` exists, you've got two `__setattr__`s and both are broken, I don't know why you even tried to do `self.model.__getattribute__('bool_custom_trained')` when that makes no sense, a bunch of your methods try to access `self.instance` for some weird reason, and that's all without touching on all the missing context. Your code is seriously messed up.

Comment: Some of the stuff that doesn't make sense is inherited from the resource you were reading, which also doesn't make sense. It's crazy old, and it looks like someone tried to update it for new-at-the-time language features without understanding them. Even before the update, it wasn't great, though.

Comment: I just tried to implement singleton  quickly because I need only one object, and need to call the same object from several places. I wanted to use it as a kind of global storage. As I'm still not good with python syntax, I googled singleton python and according to link I provided in question, I took that implementation and modified it with extra attribute bool_custom_trained.

Comment: @intersect What is the program as a whole meant to do? This seems like it has morphed into a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Program as a whole detects objects from video or images according to chosen model. 
User picks model by choosing tkinter Radiobutton. I thought easiest way to sync user input - with detector source is  using singleton class. (changedRadio->updateSingleton-> Idea was that was automatic update to model source in Detecror class who uses same singleton model)  Somehow I thought I provided all info relevant to problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Throw that entire book (python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io, “Python 3 Patterns, Recipes and Idioms”) away.
2. Create an instance, because this isn’t Java.

   ```
   from dataclasses import dataclass


   class Model:
       def __init__(self):
           self.name = ''
           self.bool_custom_trained = False


   model_instance = Model()
   ```
3. If you don’t trust yourself not to create more `Model`s, you can `del Model` afterwards.